# Why can't I use `&Iterator<Item = &String>` as an iterator?

Tags: rust

I have the following function that's supposed to find and return the longest length of a `String` given an `Iterator`:

```
fn max_width(strings: &Iterator<Item = &String>) -> usize {
    let mut max_width = 0;
    for string in strings {
        if string.len() > max_width {
            max_width = string.len();
        }
    }
    return max_width;
}
```

However, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::iter::Iterator<Item=&std::string::String>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     for string in strings {
  |                   ^^^^^^^ `&std::iter::Iterator<Item=&std::string::String>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::iter::Iterator<Item=&std::string::String>`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

I'm new to Rust, and terribly confused by this, since I thought I was explicitly passing in an iterator. Calling `strings.iter()` tells me that it is not implemented, and calling `strings.into_iter()` sends me down a mutability rabbit-hole, and I certainly don't want to mutate the passed argument.

How can I iterate over my strings?

Comment: It's idiomatic rust to omit `return` at the end of functions. Just write `max_width` (without semicolon).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code fails because [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) is not the same as `&Iterator`. You can fix this if you pass `Iterator` to your function, but since `Iterator` is a trait, the size cannot be determined (You can't know, what `Iterator` you are passing). The solution is to pass anything that implements `Iterator`:

```
fn max_width<'a>(strings: impl Iterator<Item = &'a String>) -> usize
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=afa2a7d70b42cdd6dcd50e2a6daa02e6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

---

For more experienced Rust users:

The most generic way is probably this:

```
fn max_width<T: AsRef<str>>(strings: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> usize {
    let mut max_width = 0;
    for string in strings {
        let string = string.as_ref();
        if string.len() > max_width {
            max_width = string.len();
        }
    }
    max_width
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e2ab041731d4aeee1392ca45c7b158db&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

However, you can also use

```
fn max_width<T: AsRef<str>>(strings: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> usize {
    strings
        .into_iter()
        .map(|s| s.as_ref().len())
        .max()
        .unwrap_or(0)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cfcedd56e9b7e9005df22bb13d23b2a5&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: This works, but I'm struggling to understand the semantics. I get that `Iterator` is a trait (and thus could be anything that implements that trait), but I'm confused about the `impl` keyword in this context. How does that end up with us having a known size when we didn't have it before?

Comment: I recommend reading [this](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/2018/transitioning/traits/impl-trait.html). Basically, it's the same as `fn max_width<'a, T: Iterator<Item = &'a String>(strings: T) -> usize`.

Comment: Oh! So `Iterator` *is the trait itself*, and `impl Iterator` is something that implements that trait. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I think [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html) matches the old link.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers show you *how* to accept an iterator, but gloss over answering your actual question:

> Why can't I use `&Iterator<Item = &String>` as an iterator?

Amusingly enough, you've prevented it yourself:

> and I certainly don't want to mutate the passed argument

Iterators work by mutating their target — that's how the iterator can change to return a new value for each call!

```
pub trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
    //       ^^^
}
```

By taking in an immutable *trait object*, it's impossible for your iterator to update itself, thus it's impossible to actually iterate.

The absolute smallest thing you can do to make your code compile is to accept a mutable reference:

```
fn max_width(strings: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &String>) -> usize
```

However, I'd probably write the function as:

```
fn max_width<I>(strings: I) -> usize
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    strings
        .into_iter()
        .map(|s| s.as_ref().len())
        .max()
        .unwrap_or(0)
}
```

1. Don't use an explicit `return`
2. Use iterator combinators like [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and [`max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max)
3. Use [`Option::unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) to provide a default.
4. Use [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) to accept anything that can be made into an iterator.

Comment: I prefer this answer since it also offers a solution close to OP's initial intent, using dynamic polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically need the generality of iterating over any given iterator, a simpler way to write the function is to have your `max_width` function take a `&[&str]` (A slice of string slices) instead. You can use a slice in a `for` loop because Rust knows how to turn that into an iterator (it implements `IntoIterator` trait):

```
fn max_width(strings: &[&str]) -> usize {
    let mut max_width = 0;
    for string in strings {
        if string.len() > max_width {
            max_width = string.len();
        }
    }
    return max_width;
}

fn main() {
    let strings = vec![
        "following",
        "function",
        "supposed",
        "return",
        "longest",
        "string",
        "length"
    ];

    let max_width = max_width(&strings);

    println!("Longest string had size {}", max_width);
}

// OUTPUT: Longest string had size 9
```

[Playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4770d47bd942799b0eb1bd451d34b363&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Thanks, I'll update. Do `&String`'s also deref to `&str` and would you not pass that instead? I thought maybe OP being new to Rust just wanted to iterate a bunch of strings and a Vec seemed like an easy way to do that. The generic solution is interesting though.

Comment: My apologies, I should have added my use case! I was unpacking fields from a vector of structs (`max_width(recipes.iter().map(|x| &x.name))`) so I already had an iterator, hence the function using that instead of a vector.

Comment: @pjf If you may consider replacing it with this: `recipes.iter().map(|x| x.name.len()).max().unwrap_or(0)`

Comment: You may add your use case to the question as well :)