# How to accept both Vec<String> and Vec<str> as function arg in Rust

Tags: string, generics, vector, rust

I'm working on my first Rust crate and I wanted to make my API a bit more user friendly by allowing both `foo(vec!["bar", "baz"])` and `foo(vec![String::from("foo"), String::from("baz")])`.

So far I've managed to accept both `String` and `&str` but I'm struggling to do the same for `Vec<T>`.

```rust
fn foo<S: Into<String>>(string: S) -> String {
    string.into()
}

fn foo_many<S: Into<String>>(strings: Vec<S>) -> Vec<String> {
    strings.iter().map(|s| s.into()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(String::from("bar")));
    println!("{}", foo("baz"));

    for string in foo_many(vec!["foo", "bar"]) {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<&S>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:6:30
  |
6 |     strings.iter().map(|s| s.into()).collect()
  |                              ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&S>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where std::string::String: std::convert::From<&S>` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<std::string::String>` for `&S`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a trait method taking an iterator of strings, avoiding monomorphization (static dispatch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225766/how-to-write-a-trait-method-taking-an-iterator-of-strings-avoiding-monomorphiza)

Comment: I have retract my vote, the other question is probably too confusing for newbie, sorry for that.

Comment: Using `AsRef<str>` might be more useful than `Into<String>`. Also note that by converting into String, you're probably unnecessarily allocating strings into the heap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can go for full generic, you don't need to force user to use a `Vec`, better you can take a generic type that implement [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) that you just have to write that `Item` implement [`Into<String>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html), the syntax is somehow strange and logic. You need a second generic type to do it. I call `I` the type that will be the iterator and T the Item type.

```rust
fn foo<S: Into<String>>(string: S) -> String {
    string.into()
}

fn foo_many<I, T>(iter: I) -> Vec<String>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: Into<String>,
{
    iter.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(String::from("bar")));
    println!("{}", foo("baz"));

    for string in foo_many(vec!["foo", "bar"]) {
        println!("{}", string);
    }

    for string in foo_many(vec![foo("foo"), foo("baz")]) {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
}
```

This solve your problem and make your function even more generic.

Comment: I haven't even thought about allowing other iterable structures but that's definitely an even more flexible solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work because your iteration doesn't give you `S` but `&S`.

If you want to *move* the strings out of the vector, you must make it mutable and drain it:

```
fn foo_many<S: Into<String>>(mut strings: Vec<S>) -> Vec<String> {
    strings.drain(..).map(|s| s.into()).collect()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1dbec3e0047be6fb3785547721af60f1)

Comment: @MartinSotirov I added a link to the playground. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link. That's exactly what I need. Thanks.